# Attempting to get numberOfRowsInSection count to be equal to an array count from another file in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

Currently I am fetching data from firebase, turning the data into an array of objects and trying to have that array count be the count of the "numberOfRowsInSection". 
So, I get the right count on the view controller where the array is declare but I keep getting 0's when I pass that data to the tableview controller.

Below I am showing the viewcontroller where I am fetching data and putting it in a filtered array:

```
 func fetchAllData( completion: @escaping (_ call: [Restaurant]) -> Void) {

    self.ref = Database.database().reference()
    self.ref?.observe(.value, with: { (snap) in
        guard let topArray = snap.value as? [[String:Any]] else {print(":(") ; return }
        var restaurantArray = [Restaurant]()

        for dictionary in topArray {
            self.restaurantGroup.enter()
            guard let address = dictionary["Address"] as? String,
                let city = dictionary["City"] as? String,
                let inspectionDate = dictionary["Inspection Date"] as? String,
                let name = dictionary["Name"] as? String,
                let major = dictionary["Number of Occurrences (Critical Violations)"] as? Int,
                let minor = dictionary["Number of Occurrences (Noncritical Violations)"] as? Int,
                let violationTitle = dictionary["Violation Title"] as? String else { continue }
            print(2)
            //MARK: - creates restaurants from the list above
            let restaurant = Restaurant(address: address, city: city, inspectionDate: inspectionDate, name: name, major: major, minor: minor, violationTitle: violationTitle)

            print(3)
            //MARK: - Adds a restaurant to restaurant array instance
            restaurantArray.append(restaurant)
        }
        self.restaurantList = restaurantArray
        self.restaurantGroup.leave()
        completion(self.restaurantList)

        let dictionaryNew = Dictionary(grouping: self.restaurantList) { $0.name + " " + $0.address}

        self.restaurantListModified = dictionaryNew
        print(self.restaurantListModified.count)
     })
     }

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    var filteredArray = [[Restaurant]]()
    guard let userSearch = searchBar.text?.uppercased() else { return }
    pulleyViewController?.setDrawerPosition(position: .partiallyRevealed, animated: true)

    var nameArray = [String]()

    for (key, value) in restaurantListModified {

        if value[0].name.hasPrefix(userSearch.uppercased()){
            filteredArray.append(value)
        }
    }

    for subarray in filteredArray {
        let nameArrayForTBView = subarray[0].name
        nameArray.append(nameArrayForTBView)
    }
    self.tableViewNameArray = nameArray
    print("\(tableViewNameArray.count)")
    print("this First")
}
}
```

The tableViewNameArray is the array I am trying to pass to this tableView Controller

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    print("This second")
   print(MapViewController.sharedMapViewController.tableViewNameArray.count)

    return MapViewController.sharedMapViewController.tableViewNameArray.count

}
```

I also have my array set to a Notification Center that is received in the tableView Controller as shown below:

```
var tableViewNameArray = [String]() {

    didSet {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: MapViewController.RestaurantNotification.notificationSet, object: self)
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Points:

1. My array from viewcontroller is getting the right count on the view controller but the accurate count is not being passed to the tableView Controller.
2. the tableview count for the array being passed is 0

Comment: You actually need to reload the tableview when new data is passed on to it. That is the only way numberOfRowsInSection function get called again. So, when you set the property observer tableViewNameArray, you need to call tableview.reloadData() method in the main thread to trigger up the process again with the new data.

Comment: I am about to test it out. I had the observer on the tableview controller like this:            
   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reloadTableView), name: MapViewController.RestaurantNotification.notificationSet, object: nil)
        
    }
    
Should I do something different?

Comment: What happens inside the reloadTableView function?

Comment: here is the function:     @objc func reloadTableView() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.restaurantListTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

Comment: You think maybe I should take the main async off?

Comment: Not really.
Why the nested DispatchQueue below?
var tableViewNameArray = [String]() {

    didSet {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: MapViewController.RestaurantNotification.notificationSet, object: self)
        }
        }
    }

}

Comment: Haha. I was testing out the different things I saw others doing on GitHub.

Comment: When I take it out, it actually runs the tableview first and then the map view second but that's it. When I dispatch to main, it runs after map but it prints a 0 count.

Comment: what is `sharedMapViewController`? Add this line `print(MapViewController.sharedMapViewController.tableViewNameArray.count)` at the end of `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` method to see if the assignment is working? It would be better to include both classes in your question.

Comment: You're right, it's not being assigned. that returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem that @Kamran pointed to. I was not assigning  self.tableViewNameArray = nameArray. So I changed

```
var tableViewNameArray to 
static var tableViewNameArray
```

If you're new to programming like I, make sure you read a bit more on local and global variables. Very helpful.